# A strange crease appeared on my mesh after adding a loop cut

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view, edit-mode

So I'm not exactly sure if it was a direct consequence of creating the loop cut, because it was only after editing (grabbing & moving) it around a little bit that I noticed the crease.
Anyway, here's a picture:

[image]

The loop cut I mentioned is selected in the picture.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this and make the surface smooth again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inner faces, you can see it if you hide the outer faces, remove them:

[image]